# How can i run a python file as service python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-daemon

I have a python script and that I have to run as a service/background process, I have tried python-daemon but it gives me errors is there any good way to run it as a service so that the script can be run in the background to accept messages and process files?

Comment: Can you provide the errors you are receiving?

Comment: os.umask(022) # Don't allow others to write

Comment: This is what i have tried "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/"

Comment: Again please provide a code example that you have tried and the errors you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a sytemctl service file in /lib/systemed/system 
The file content is

```
[Unit]
Description=RPC SERVER
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ python3 /home/ubuntu/rpc.py


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/home/ubuntu/rpc.py is my python script path
and i saved the file as rpcservertest.service
so i can start the service using 
sudo systemctl start rpcservertest.service
to stop
sudo systemctl stop rpcservertest.service
and to get status
sudo systemctl status rpcservertest.service